# Automatically upload matplotlib plot to very simple http server

Tags: python, http, matplotlib, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set up a very simple http site on my local machine with this code.

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write("hello world".encode())


def main():
    PORT = 8000
    server = HTTPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
    print(f"Server running on port {PORT}")
    server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ultimately, I want to setup the site in a way, that it displays a matplotlib plot, which I am generating with my machine. I accomplished this with the `mpld3` package.
The problem is, that my python code continuously updates the plot (it is displaying the temperature over time), and the `mpld3` generated image is static.

If anyone could point out how I can send the newly generated plot to the HTTP site to be displayed every X seconds, I would be very happy.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm confused, is it continuously updated or is it static? every time an update happens push the change to your server

Comment: I add a new datapoint every X seconds which then gets plotted. It is fine if the plot gets newly generated each time on my machine and then gets pushed to the http site. 
Unfortunately I am an absolute noob when it comes to HTTP. Could you explain how I would implement such a "push" to the HTTP site?

Comment: you could use the `requests` module to make a POST request with your graph as the data. make sure to make a POST handler on your server

Comment: How would I write such a do_POST handler? Would I send the graph as the payload with the post request?

Comment: I can't give you a full answer, but ill try to give you some pointers. `mpld3.fig_to_dict` will give you a json serializable dict on which you can use `json.dumps`. with `requests.post` you can send that json to you server. on the do_POST you can read the json from `self.rfile` you should look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler)